# Change body font without affecting titles, section titles etc

Tags: fonts

I'm using the package CormorantGaramond, which changes many of the fonts in my document, i.e. section titles, chapter titles, which I'm happy with. However, I would like to change the font on all of the regular (i.e. body) text in the doc without affecting the section/chapter title fonts and without having to wrap my text in a command.

How can I do this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{CormorantGaramond}
\title{Nice CormorantGaramond Title}
\author{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Nice CormorantGaramond section title}
\subsection{Nice CormorantGaramond subsection title}
I want all of this text to be computer modern.

\end{document}
```

Comment: You want titles in Computer Modern and the body font in Cormorant Garamond? This will look horrible!

Comment: No, the other way round! I want the body to be CM and the titles Cormorant Garamond....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most titles use `\normalfont`, which in this case is CG.  `\maketitle` does not.  You can switch back and forth using `\normalfont` and `\cmfont` if needed.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\edef\cmfamily{\familydefault}
\usepackage{CormorantGaramond}
\title{Nice CormorantGaramond Title}
\author{}

\newcommand{\cmfont}{\usefont\encodingdefault
  \cmfamily
  \seriesdefault
  \shapedefault
  \relax}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\cmfont

\section{Nice CormorantGaramond section title}
\subsection{Nice CormorantGaramond subsection title}
I want all of this text to be computer modern.

{\normalfont But this is in CormorantGaramond}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I want the section/subsection etc fonts to be CormorantGaramond (which they are, the package does that), but I want the body text to all be CM. Ideally without having to wrap every bit of body text in {\command } as my document is 150 pages long!

Comment: It should stay in \cmfont unless you take it out.  Most uses of \normalfont are done inside groups, so the change is local to the group.